# jQuery spinner from hard-coded array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/P4buM/1/). How can I make the spinner add values from the `opa` array on each clicks on minus or plus buttons?

Here is the code I have:

```
<div class="btn-group input-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default minus">-</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">%</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default opacity">0</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default plus">+</button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var opa = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90];
    $(".plus").on("click", function () {
        $(".opacity").html(opa[1]);
    });
    $(".minus").on("click", function () {
        $(".opacity").html(opa[0]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var opa = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90];
    var i=0;
    $(".plus").on("click", function () {
        if(i<9) $(".opacity").html(opa[++i]);
    });
    $(".minus").on("click", function () {
        if(i>0) $(".opacity").html(opa[--i]);
    });
});
```

Comment: After voting up to the last item if you click yhe plus sign again and if you start voting down , the first click not worrking!

Comment: Is there any way to disable the key when it reach the max + or _ number?

Comment: @user1760110 disabled, inside `if` statements you can additionally change css to make buttons seem disabled.